# error: expected primary expression before const in ns3 while connecting two NodeContainers via P2P channel

Tags: c++, p2p

**Here is my Code I have two Node Containers and I am Getting the Error Please Help me To Solve this:**

```
  NodeContainer nodes;
  nodes.Create (2); //creat 2 nodes they are p2p

  PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
  pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("2Mbps"));
  pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("20ms"));

  NetDeviceContainer devices;// put nodes in ndc
  devices = pointToPoint.Install (nodes);
////give them an address
  InternetStackHelper stack;
  stack.Install (nodes);
    Ipv4AddressHelper address;
    address.SetBase ("109.11.12.0", "255.255.255.0");//address setting

    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces = address.Assign (devices);
////Node Container 1 End Here...

/////Node Contatiner 2
  NodeContainer nodes1;

  nodes1.Add(nodes.Get(1));
  nodes1.Create (2); //creat 2 nodes they are p2p


  PointToPointHelper pointToPoint1;
  pointToPoint1.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("2Mbps"));
  pointToPoint1.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("20ms"));

  NetDeviceContainer devices1;// put nodes in ndc
  devices1 = pointToPoint1.Install (nodes1);
////give them an address
  InternetStackHelper stack1;
  stack1.Install (nodes1);
    Ipv4AddressHelper address1;
    address1.SetBase ("107.11.12.0", "255.255.255.0");//address setting

    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces1 = address.Assign (devices1);
////Node Container 2 End Here..


/////Node Contatiner 3
  NodeContainer nodes2;

 nodes2.Add(const NodeContainer &nodes,const NodeContainer &nodes1);
```

***Showing Me This Error... Searched alot but No Solution Found....***

```
../scratch/Test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../scratch/Test.cc:214:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  nodes2.Add(const NodeContainer &nodes,const NodeContainer &nodes1); //creat 2 nodes they are p2p
             ^
../scratch/Test.cc:214:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
  nodes2.Add(const NodeContainer &nodes,const NodeContainer &nodes1); //creat 2 nodes they are p2p
```

Help me where are am doing wrong.... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Functions expect already declared arguments, not new definitions.

Try again with this.

```
 const NodeContainer nodes;
 const NodeContainer nodes1;
 nodes2.Add(&nodes,&nodes1);
```

Comment: Thanks Done With It